# Метод прогонки/Алгоритм Томаса(С++)

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Здраствуйте!
Хотел бы попросить Вас о маленькой помощи. Проблема заключается в следующем : должен найти решения матрицы методом прогонки и в конечном итоге получаю корректные значение в точках, но они симметрически противоположны к тем, котрые должны быть, т.е когда я умножаю вектор результатов на -1 на выходе получаю то, что меня инетересует.
На графике выглядит следующим образом : [image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Это то, что должны быть в итоге, а у меня два нижние горба сверху, а тот, что по середине - снизу и точка с которой график старта и конца в -1, а не в 1. Алгоритм и индексы уже переверял много раз + в следующих лабах юзая данную имеплементацию функции все работает коректно.
Возможно кто-то знает как с этим справиться, был бы очень признателен за помощь! Хорошего дня :)

Код :

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define N 1000

void thomas_algorithm(const std::vector<double>& a,
                      const std::vector<double>& b,
                      const std::vector<double>& c,
                      const std::vector<double>& d,
                      std::vector<double>& f) {

  std::vector<double> beta(N+1,0.);
  std::vector<double> gama(N+1,0.);

  beta[0] = - c[0] / b[0];
  gama[0] = -1. / b[0];

  for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    double n = 1. / (b[i] + a[i] * beta[i-1]);
    beta[i] = -c[i] * n;
    gama[i] = (d[i] - (a[i] * gama[i-1])) * n;
  }

  f[0] = 1;
  f[N] = -1;    

  for (int i = (N - 1); i > 0; i--) {
    f[i] = gama[i] + beta[i] * f[i+1];
  } 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  double h = 0.01;

  std::vector<double> a(N+1);
  std::vector<double> b(N+1);
  std::vector<double> c(N+1);
  std::vector<double> d(N+1,0.);
  std::vector<double> f(N+1);

   int i = 0;
   while(i < N){
     a[i] = c[i] = 1./(h*h);
     b[i] = (-2./(h*h)) + 1.;
     i++;
   }

   a[0] = 0.; a[N] = 1.;
   b[0] = 1.; b[N] = -2.;
   c[0] = 0.; c[N] = 1.;  

    thomas_algorithm(a, b, c, d, f);

//  for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++){
//      f[i] *= -1; 
//  }

    for(int i = 1; i < N; i++){
        std::cout << i*h << ". " << f[i] << std::endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы **даже** не написали, какое уравнение пытаетесь решить...

Comment: @Harry, да, извиняюсь, забыл :(
Вот : https://imgur.com/a/jtrCuA5

Comment: Чтобы решить данную систему уравнений методом прогонки я сделал маленькую модификацию :
1. Было :  y[N-1] - 2*y[n] + y[0] = 0;
2. Стало  : y[N-1] - 2*y[n] - 1 = 0  =>  y[N-1] - 2*y[n] = -1.
Т.е в векторе свободных коефициентов последний член будет равен : y[N] = -1.
Это согласовал с преподом и он подтвердил, что так можно и правильно и все матрицы заполнены правильно, только вот этот знак где-то вылазит...

Comment: Вопрос не актуален, чтобы данный код работал просто нужно убрать с[N] = 1.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что сам автор написал, что вопрос не актуален.